# Initialize webdriver in Cucumber 6

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How to initialize webdrivermanager java and DAO/Spring/ once in Cucumber?

Any @BeforeSuite or @AfterSuite similar mechanism?

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/resources/Features",
        glue = "com.cimb.StepsDef",
        plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                "json:target/cucumber-report.json"})
public class ParallelRunner {
}
```

Cucumber supports JUnits @ClassRule, @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations. These will executed before and after all scenarios. Using these is not recommended, as it limits the portability between different runners; they may not execute correctly when using the commandline, IntelliJ IDEA or Cucumber-Eclipse. Instead it is recommended to use Cucumbers Before and After hooks.

Please provide some sample code. A billion thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `cucumber-guice` to initialize webdriver. This will also make your tests scenarios independent as a new driver instance is created for every scenario. Here is what I do to use it

To use below code you will need `cucumber-guice` dependency

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In chromemanager class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;

public class ChromeManager extends DriverManager {

     protected ChromeDriver driver;
    
         @Override
         protected WebDriver createDriver() {

                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/../chromedriver");
                    return driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService());
        }

        @Override
         public WebDriver getDriver() {
                 if (driver == null) {
                             this.createDriver();
                }
                return driver;
        }

}
```

Driverfactory class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DriverFactory {
        public WebDriver getManager() {

            return new ChromeManager().getDriver();
        }
}
```

Drivermanager class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

     public abstract class DriverManager {

                     protected abstract WebDriver createDriver();
                     public abstract WebDriver getDriver();
     }
```

and then in a global class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;  
 
 @ScenarioScoped
    
          public class Global {
          public WebDriver driver;
           public WebDriverWait wait;
        
          public Global() {
                driver = new DriverFactory().getManager();
                wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
    
          }
    
    }
```

and finally your test class

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;     
import com.test.support.Global;    


public class InitialIT  {

         public static  ChromeDriver driver ;
                     
        @Inject
        Global global;
            
    @Test
       @Given("I open the site {string}")
        public void OpenSite(String site) throws MalformedURLException {                 
                global.driver.get(site);                   
       }
                      
         @After
        public void closeBrowser() {    
             global.driver.quit();
      }

}
```

If you are using junit jupiter. You can also use [`selenium-jupiter`](https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter) to manage webdriver

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was using the same approach as you mentioned in your "Global" class, it was working with cucumber version 4, but when I upgraded to cucumber 7.0.0 version, I'm getting below error while running a test: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) [Guice/ScopeNotFound]: No scope is bound to ScenarioScoped.